# Credentials are required php twilio

Tags: php, twilio, sms, twilio-api

I'm trying to use Twilio's API to send a sms with PHP.
I followed the tutorial as it is presented on their website but it doesn't work. I correctly replaced the $sid, $token, "from number" and "to number" variables. I also tested it with Phyton and it worked correctly, but with PHP I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Twilio\Exceptions\ConfigurationException:
> Credentials are required to create a Client in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Php\Twilio\vendor\twilio\sdk\src\Twilio\Rest\Client.php:172
> Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Php\Twilio\index.php(13):
> Twilio\Rest\Client->__construct('', '') #1

I'm using PHP 7.3.21 and xampp. I've saw this same error with people using laravel and more complex codes, but I'm using "pure" PHP.
The code I'm using:

```
<?php

// Update the path below to your autoload.php,
// see https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
// and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
$sid = getenv("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID");
$token = getenv("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN");
$twilio = new Client($sid, $token);

$message = $twilio->messages
                  ->create("+15558675310", // to
                           [
                               "body" => "This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs?",
                               "from" => "+15017122661"
                           ]
                  );

print($message->sid);
```

You can find the tutorial that I followed here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-send-sms-messages-php

Comment: check your `$sid` and `$token` if they have the correct values

Comment: @B001ᛦ I've also sent them a ticket

Comment: @AndréWalker I did it and it's correct. I used their python code with the same $sid and $token values and worked well.

Comment: Are you sure that `getenv("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID")` is returning the account sid? Same question for the auth token.

Comment: @philnash apparently that's the problem. It's returning an empty string. I tried to add both variables following this: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/windows-set-environment-variable but it's still not working.

Comment: But you were able to set the environment variables for your Python version? Are you running the PHP inside some sort of container that is setting its own environment variables?

Comment: Yeah, I was able to set them with Python. I fixed it after restarting my PC some times and now the environment variables are working. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a problem with the environment variables. I hardcoded them but the `getenv()` was returning an empty string and I don't know why it was happening. So to fix it I set them following this tutorial (for windows): phoenixnap.com/kb/windows-set-environment-variable. For linux you can try using these commands:

```
export ACCOUNT_SID="YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID"
export AUTH_TOKEN="YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN"
```

And then, in your code, for windows and linux:

```
$sid = getenv('ACCOUNT_SID');
$token = getenv('AUTH_TOKEN');
```

Make sure to restart xampp (if you're using it) and your computer after setting your variables.